# What gc logs graph mean?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Here is the graph
[image]

And also I have this in the end of log file

```
2601.692: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 379102K->0K(2799104K)] [ParOldGen: 6821274K->3862331K(6774272K)] 7200377K->3862331K(9573376K), [Metaspace: 40830K->40830K(1087488K)], 0.4856957 secs] [Times: user=4.59 sys=0.02, real=0.48 secs] 
2602.835: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2419712K->56704K(2930688K)] 6282043K->3919035K(9704960K), 0.0085938 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
Heap
   PSYoungGen total 2930688K, used 2130522K [0x00000006eab00000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
   eden space 2370560K, 87% used [0x00000006eab00000,0x0000000769436bf0,0x000000077b600000)
   from space 560128K, 10% used [0x000000079dd00000,0x00000007a1460000,0x00000007c0000000)
   to space 562176K, 0% used [0x000000077b600000,0x000000077b600000,0x000000079db00000)
   ParOldGen total 6774272K, used 3862331K [0x0000000540000000, 0x00000006dd780000, 0x00000006eab00000)
   object space 6774272K, 57% used [0x0000000540000000,0x000000062bbced40,0x00000006dd780000)
   Metaspace used 44005K, capacity 45394K, committed 45736K, reserved 1089536K
   class space used 5210K, capacity 5519K, committed 5544K, reserved 1048576K
```

And next exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Can I take from it some more information, beside that at some moment program creates a lot of objects?
And is there any way to resolve this issue

Comment: *This is a guess:* Seems your code occasionally runs a task that uses 2-5 GB of memory (see the first 5 spikes). Then it began doing 3 or more of those tasks at the same time, causing the JVM to run out of memory. Once memory use exceeded 9 GB, the JVM slowed down, running in circles, while GC starts trying to find any scrap of free memory, until it finally can't find any more and crashes.

Comment: *Solution 1:* Add more memory (unlikely to help, it'll just defer the issue). --- *Solution 2:* Change the code of the task in question to use less memory. --- *Solution 3:* Change the code so the program only runs one of those expensive tasks at a time.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to run with -Xmx30G and will try to optimize my code as second solution in same time. I reallu dont wont to make third solution, because it will slow my code too much

Comment: And crashing is not slowing it down?

Comment: Im not quite understand. If you mean program - yes it is stopped when out of memory exception is shown

Comment: you say you don't want to redesign your app because that would slow it down. You current solution crashes. Is that not slowing it down?

Comment: I always have solution with throwing more memory into heap and its kinda works